# Деепричастие без глагола

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

> Коронавирусная пневмония отличается от других видов пневмоний, включая
>   осложнения гриппа, или нет?

Уши подсказывают, что предложение хорошо составлено и нет никаких противоречий. Но правила русского языка настаивают на обратном:
деепричастный оборот, как и деепричастие, всегда являются (или -ться?) добавочным действием к некоторому глаголу.
А в данном предложении, очевидно, такой глагол отсутствует.

Чему в данном случае верить — ушам или правилам?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашлось [правильное](https://www.kp.ru/daily/27110.7/4185598/) (полное) предложение:
*— Давайте сразу расставим точки над i: коронавирусная пневмония отличается от других видов пневмоний, включая осложнения гриппа, или явных особенностей все-таки нет?*

В этом предложении «включая» — это предлог, который образован от деепричастия (соответствует по значению словам *вместе с кем-либо* или *вместе чем-либо, в том числе*).
При оборотах с предлогом «включая» запятая нужна в большинстве случаев, кроме предложений с особой авторской пунктуацией.

> Поэтому можно обречь доверенную по мандату страну оставаться пустыней, можно запретить туда доступ всем, **включая** научные экспедиции, лишь бы алмазы навсегда остались лежать в песках Берега Скелетов бесполезными сокровищами (И. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы).

Не нужно путать собственно с деепричастием.

> Вспомним о погибших товарищах! — сказал начальник, **включая** экран проектора, на котором появился «Альграб», снятый перед отлетом «Тантры» (И. Ефремов. Туманность Андромеды).

[Значение слова «включая»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F)

P. S. *Деепричастный оборот, как и деепричастие, всегда* (что делаю**т**?) *являю**т**ся...*
P. P. S. Лучше говорить ***обозначают*** добавочное действие.

Comment: Спасибо, я сразу подумал на предлог, но меня смутило обрамление запятыми как у деепричастного оборота. PS. А что насчет: "Из дома вышел или Вася или Маша". Здесь-то множественное число явно не подходит? С другой стороны и мужской род тоже не очень смотрится. Подошел бы средний род единственное число, но так не говорят. Проблема остается даже в таком предложении "Из дома вышел Вася или может быть это была Маша"